# How to write a for loop in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

one question bothers me. I'm reading a file that has coordinates(longitude and latitude).

The contents of the file: **50.29264389999999,18.91857099999993;50.0347499,21.967057000000068;54.4547473,17.042384500000026;**

I made a class for the coordinates

```
internal class Coordinate
    {
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public Coordinate(double longitude,double latitude)
        {
            this.Longitude = longitude;
            this.Latitude = latitude;
        }
    }
```

And I use this code to read the file and list them.

```
List<Coordinate> cordinates = new List<Coordinate>();
var items = File.ReadAllText("../../../Files/input-01.txt").Split(new char[] { ',', ';' }).Select(double.Parse).ToList();
for(int i = 0; i < items.Count; i+=2)
{
    cordinates.Add(new Coordinate(items[i], items[i + 1]));
}
```

The program works, but is there a way to write this for loop in LINQ ?

Comment: is it all one line. Are the lines always the same length?

Comment: @pm100 Yes they are.

Comment: `File.ReadAllText("..").Split(';').Select(x => x.Split(',').Select(double.Parse)).Select(x => new Coordinate(x.First(), x.Last())).ToList();`?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: the LINQ ways is absolutely magic (thanks @juharr!) but it's far harder to read and understand than the obvious but less fun way.

Comment: @juharr Linq is truly a double-edged sword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's try to pick each coordinate once

```
File.ReadAllText(filepath).Split(';')
```

To clarify your code add a new function to your coordinate class as this

```
public Coordinatex(string[] s){this.Longitude = double.Parse(s.First());this.Latitude = double.Parse(s.Last());}
```

Then put all items as coordinate objets by splitting and casting to double, so the result maybe looks like this

```
File.ReadAllText(filepath).Split(';').Select(x => new Coordinatex(x.Split(',')));
```

Hope this works to you

Comment: That's not going to work because `x.Split(',')` returns an array and the constructor for `Coordinatex` takes two parameters.  I'm also not familiar with the term "matador function", are you talking about Python code where you can pass an array to a function that takes individual parameters?

Comment: @juharr yeah thank you I edited. I Try to keep things inside the class to apply more encapsulation and make the code clear, otherwise yes, those all could be apply in one line like your comment. It was perfect.